# Power usage in Task Manager says "very high"

Tags: windows-10, power-supply, power, cpu-usage, ups

I am running the next parts:

- SMPS 750W
- Ryzen 9 3900x
- RTX 3060
- 24 inches led monitor

These parts are connected to 600 VA ups and wherever I run a software I see my power usage shoot up very high and in a very light software as AutoCAD I see some lags and flickers. My CPU is connected to the ups with a 16amp to 5 amp converter as it has a power plug. I am not sure but i think either this converter is causing this or my ups is on a lighter end.

Please clarify also is there any other possibility of this cause.

Answer (score 2):

According to my calculations, the 600 VA of the UPS is below the
need of your hardware.

Verify using a Power Supply Calculator like
[OuterVision](https://outervision.com/power-supply-calculator)
to calculate your exact needs, then get a UPS (and PSU) with
a comfortable power margin.

Do not run without enough power, or you risk your hardware.

Comment: so is it just ups or the converter may be creating an issue here?

Comment: Nothing is ever sure about computer, but I think so.

Comment: I think there are multiple things going on here - the 600VA UPS is definitely under-specced and should be upgraded.   What is a "16 amp to 5 amp converter?"  This makes little sense, as computers use fixed voltage, so amps are drawn "as required - converters make no sense.   Your lags and flickers and power usage are likely due to software/drivers and are likely unrelated to your UPS issues.

Comment: Its worth asking what country you are in / what voltage comes out the wall.  5 amps at 110 volts is only 550 watts, which could mean you have a fire hazard.  5 amps at 220 volts is 1100 watts which should be ample.